# Regex/Jquery - Remove String / Keep Int

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Not overly familiar with regex, I'm working with a custom calendar, and need to be able to parse out the month and year into separate variables.

To get my date, I am using kendo UI's month picker, so I just grab .val on change. Here is my code below, I've managed to get parse out the month, just need to create a regex that will parse out the year into a var called calYear:

```
$("#MonthPicker").change(function () {
    var x = $(this).val();
    console.log(x);
    var calMonth = x.replace(/\d+/g, ''); 
    console.log(calMonth);
});
```

Here is my console's output:

```
November 2013 <-- This is var x
November <-- This is var calMonth
```

Comment: show how the date will be

Comment: so, you want `November`? What's wrong with your code?

Comment: No, I just want the year.

Comment: Use split() with a space delimiter. This will put both in array indexes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `String#split` to get both values in **single operation**:

```
var tok = 'November 2013'.split(' ');
var month = tok[0]; // November
var year = tok[1]; // 2013
```

Answer (score 2):

By given info, you can use this:

```
var calMonth = x.match(/\d{4}$/g)[0];
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for. Give you the answer as soon as SO will let me.

Comment: @Mark glad to have helped :)

Comment: @Mark I had the idea of split, but you hadn't provided the example.. so, just use split() and you can choose the other answer as your answer..